# How to echo XML as simple string?

Tags: php, echo

I am not able to understand the behaviour of the code :

Input :

```
<?php
    function polldaddy_choices($choices) {
      foreach ($choices as $choice) {
        $answer = "<pd:answer>
                   <pd:text>" . $choice . "</pd:text>
                   </pd:answer>";
        echo $answer; 
     }
  }
  $total_choices = array('yes' , 'no' , 'do not know');
  $ans = polldaddy_choices($total_choices); 
  $xml = "world" . $ans . "hello" ;
  echo $xml;
?>
```

Output :

```
  <pd:answer>
      <pd:text></pd:text>
      </pd:answer><pd:answer>
      <pd:text></pd:text>
      </pd:answer><pd:answer>
      <pd:text></pd:text>
      </pd:answer>worldhello
```

Why the string are coming at the end of the output ?

Here is the link on codepad : http://codepad.org/2dbiCelb

Comment: Is there one line or statement you don't understand?

Comment: why the string "hello" and "world" are coming to end of the output? I have put that in the starting and in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function was echoing the xml code straight away. In the code below you will see I create a variable ($answer = "";) and then append the xml at the end of the variable by using ".=". At the end of the function I return the value of $answer.

When you call the function then ($ans = polldaddy_choices($total_choices);), it will place the return value of the function into your $ans variable.

```
<?php
function polldaddy_choices($choices) {
  $answer = "";
  foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    $answer.= "<pd:answer>
               <pd:text>" . $choice . "</pd:text>
               </pd:answer>";
 }
 return $answer;
}
$total_choices = array('yes' , 'no' , 'do not know');
$ans = polldaddy_choices($total_choices); 
$xml = "world" . $ans . "hello" ;
echo $xml;
?>
```

Comment: i need the exact output as world <pd:answer>
          <pd:text>yes</pd:text>
          </pd:answer><pd:answer>
          <pd:text>no</pd:text>
          </pd:answer><pd:answer>
          <pd:text>do not know</pd:text>
          </pd:answer>hello                                                   But above code is not returning anything, my reason to use echo rather  than return is that return gives the otput as :world <pd:answer>
          <pd:text>yes</pd:text>
          </pd:answer>hello

Comment: Have you tried to run the code I placed in the comment? The exact output is :
world<pd:answer>
               <pd:text>yes</pd:text>
               </pd:answer><pd:answer>
               <pd:text>no</pd:text>
               </pd:answer><pd:answer>
               <pd:text>do not know</pd:text>
               </pd:answer>hello. The reason why it would return as world <pd:answer> <pd:text>yes</pd:text> </pd:answer>hello, is because the return command is inside the foreach loop and thus exits the function after the first element of the array is processed.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not retuning anything. You are echoing directly in that function.

So first you call `polldaddy_choices`, which echos the html. Then, you echo:

```
$xml = "world" . "" . "hello" ;
```

Comment: Strictly, `"world" . NULL . "hello"`, but the `NULL` gets treated as `""` when coerced to a string, so it's a subtle difference.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are `echo`ing the output in your `polldaddy_choices` function. So the following:

`$ans = polldaddy_choices($total_choices);` Is actually printing the XML, and:

`$xml = "world" . $ans . "hello";` will simply be printing **worldhello**, as `$ans === null`

I think you probably want to be doing something more like:

```
function polldaddy_choices($choices) {
    $answers = array();
    foreach ($choices as $choice) {
        $answer = "<pd:answer>
                   <pd:text>" . $choice . "</pd:text>
                   </pd:answer>";
        $answers[] = $answer;
    }

 return implode("\n", $answers);
}
```

Comment: so when i am trying to return the $answer instead of echo , then i get output as:world<pd:answer>
          <pd:text>do not know</pd:text>
          </pd:answer>hello  But i need this to repeat same as the no. of the strings in the array that's why i was trying to echo